# compress avi video file using directshow

Tags: c++, compression, directshow, avi

I created an avi video file but it is uncompressed and its size is large. I want to compress the video file to lower the size . I found this code but as I am beginner , I am unable to set compression. can anyone point out the way ?

This is avi class:

```
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <vfw.h>
    #include "avi_utils.h"



// First, we'll define the WAV file format.
#include <pshpack1.h>
typedef struct
{ char id[4];         //="fmt "
    unsigned long size; //=16
    short wFormatTag;   //=WAVE_FORMAT_PCM=1
    unsigned short wChannels;       //=1 or 2 for mono or stereo
    unsigned long dwSamplesPerSec;  //=11025 or 22050 or 44100
    unsigned long dwAvgBytesPerSec; //=wBlockAlign * dwSamplesPerSec
    unsigned short wBlockAlign;     //=wChannels * (wBitsPerSample==8?1:2)
    unsigned short wBitsPerSample;  //=8 or 16, for bits per sample
} FmtChunk;

typedef struct
{ char id[4];            //="data"
    unsigned long size;    //=datsize, size of the following array
    unsigned char data[1]; //=the raw data goes here
} DataChunk;

typedef struct
{ char id[4];         //="RIFF"
    unsigned long size; //=datsize+8+16+4
    char type[4];       //="WAVE"
    FmtChunk fmt;
    DataChunk dat;
} WavChunk;
#include <poppack.h>




// This is the internal structure represented by the HAVI handle:
typedef struct
{ IAVIFile *pfile;    // created by CreateAvi
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx;   // as given to CreateAvi (.nChanels=0 if none was given). Used when audio stream is first created.
    int period;         // specified in CreateAvi, used when the video stream is first created
    IAVIStream *as;     // audio stream, initialised when audio stream is first created
    IAVIStream *ps, *psCompressed;  // video stream, when first created
    unsigned long nframe, nsamp;    // which frame will be added next, which sample will be added next
    bool iserr;         // if true, then no function will do anything
} TAviUtil;


HAVI CreateAvi(const char *fn, int frameperiod, const WAVEFORMATEX *wfx)
{ IAVIFile *pfile;
    AVIFileInit();
    HRESULT hr = AVIFileOpen(&pfile, fn, OF_WRITE|OF_CREATE, NULL);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {AVIFileExit(); return NULL;}
    TAviUtil *au = new TAviUtil;
    au->pfile = pfile;
    if (wfx==NULL) ZeroMemory(&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)); else CopyMemory(&au->wfx,wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    au->period = frameperiod;
    au->as=0; au->ps=0; au->psCompressed=0;
    au->nframe=0; au->nsamp=0;
    au->iserr=false;
    return (HAVI)au;
}

HRESULT CloseAvi(HAVI avi)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
    TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
    if (au->as!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->as); au->as=0;
    if (au->psCompressed!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->psCompressed); au->psCompressed=0;
    if (au->ps!=0) AVIStreamRelease(au->ps); au->ps=0;
    if (au->pfile!=0) AVIFileRelease(au->pfile); au->pfile=0;
    AVIFileExit();
    delete au;
    return S_OK;
}


HRESULT SetAviVideoCompression(HAVI avi, HBITMAP hbm, AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS *opts, bool ShowDialog, HWND hparent)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
    if (hbm==NULL) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    DIBSECTION dibs; int sbm = GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
    if (sbm!=sizeof(DIBSECTION)) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
    if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
    if (au->psCompressed!=0) return AVIERR_COMPRESSOR;
    //
    if (au->ps==0) // create the stream, if it wasn't there before
    { AVISTREAMINFO strhdr; ZeroMemory(&strhdr,sizeof(strhdr));
    strhdr.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;// stream type
    strhdr.fccHandler = 0; 
    strhdr.dwScale = au->period;
    strhdr.dwRate = 1000;
    strhdr.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage;
    SetRect(&strhdr.rcFrame, 0, 0, dibs.dsBmih.biWidth, dibs.dsBmih.biHeight);
    HRESULT hr=AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->ps, &strhdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    if (au->psCompressed==0) // set the compression, prompting dialog if necessary
    { AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS myopts; ZeroMemory(&myopts,sizeof(myopts));
    AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS *aopts[1];
    if (opts!=NULL) aopts[0]=opts; else aopts[0]=&myopts;
    if (ShowDialog)
    { BOOL res = (BOOL)AVISaveOptions(hparent,0,1,&au->ps,aopts);
        if (!res) {AVISaveOptionsFree(1,aopts); au->iserr=true; return AVIERR_USERABORT;}
    }
    HRESULT hr = AVIMakeCompressedStream(&au->psCompressed, au->ps, aopts[0], NULL);
    AVISaveOptionsFree(1,aopts);
    if (hr != AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    DIBSECTION dibs; GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->psCompressed, 0, &dibs.dsBmih, dibs.dsBmih.biSize+dibs.dsBmih.biClrUsed*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    return AVIERR_OK;
}


HRESULT AddAviFrame(HAVI avi, HBITMAP hbm)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
    if (hbm==NULL) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    DIBSECTION dibs; int sbm = GetObject(hbm,sizeof(dibs),&dibs);
    if (sbm!=sizeof(DIBSECTION)) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
    if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
    //
    if (au->ps==0) // create the stream, if it wasn't there before
    { AVISTREAMINFO strhdr; ZeroMemory(&strhdr,sizeof(strhdr));
    strhdr.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;// stream type
    strhdr.fccHandler = 0; 
    strhdr.dwScale = au->period;
    strhdr.dwRate = 1000;
    strhdr.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage;
    SetRect(&strhdr.rcFrame, 0, 0, dibs.dsBmih.biWidth, dibs.dsBmih.biHeight);
    HRESULT hr=AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->ps, &strhdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    // create an empty compression, if the user hasn't set any
    if (au->psCompressed==0)
    { AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS opts; ZeroMemory(&opts,sizeof(opts));
    opts.fccHandler=mmioFOURCC('D','I','B',' '); 
    HRESULT hr = AVIMakeCompressedStream(&au->psCompressed, au->ps, &opts, NULL);
    if (hr != AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->psCompressed, 0, &dibs.dsBmih, dibs.dsBmih.biSize+dibs.dsBmih.biClrUsed*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    //Now we can add the frame
    HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->psCompressed, au->nframe, 1, dibs.dsBm.bmBits, dibs.dsBmih.biSizeImage, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, NULL, NULL);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    au->nframe++; return S_OK;
}



HRESULT AddAviAudio(HAVI avi, void *dat, unsigned long numbytes)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
    if (dat==NULL || numbytes==0) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
    if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
    if (au->wfx.nChannels==0) return AVIERR_BADFORMAT;
    unsigned long numsamps = numbytes*8 / au->wfx.wBitsPerSample;
    if ((numsamps*au->wfx.wBitsPerSample/8)!=numbytes) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    //
    if (au->as==0) // create the stream if necessary
    { AVISTREAMINFO ahdr; ZeroMemory(&ahdr,sizeof(ahdr));
    ahdr.fccType=streamtypeAUDIO;
    ahdr.dwScale=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwRate=au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec*au->wfx.nBlockAlign; 
    ahdr.dwSampleSize=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwQuality=(DWORD)-1;
    HRESULT hr = AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->as, &ahdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->as,0,&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    // now we can write the data
    HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->as,au->nsamp,numsamps,dat,numbytes,0,NULL,NULL);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    au->nsamp+=numsamps; return S_OK;
}



HRESULT AddAviWav(HAVI avi, const char *src, DWORD flags)
{ if (avi==NULL) return AVIERR_BADHANDLE;
    if (flags!=SND_MEMORY && flags!=SND_FILENAME) return AVIERR_BADFLAGS;
    if (src==0) return AVIERR_BADPARAM;
    TAviUtil *au = (TAviUtil*)avi;
    if (au->iserr) return AVIERR_ERROR;
    //
    char *buf=0; WavChunk *wav = (WavChunk*)src;
    if (flags==SND_FILENAME)
    { HANDLE hf=CreateFile(src,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
    if (hf==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {au->iserr=true; return AVIERR_FILEOPEN;}
    DWORD size = GetFileSize(hf,NULL);
    buf = new char[size];
    DWORD red; ReadFile(hf,buf,size,&red,NULL);
    CloseHandle(hf);
    wav = (WavChunk*)buf;
    }
    //
    // check that format doesn't clash
    bool badformat=false;
    if (au->wfx.nChannels==0)
    { au->wfx.wFormatTag=wav->fmt.wFormatTag;
    au->wfx.cbSize=0;
    au->wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec=wav->fmt.dwAvgBytesPerSec;
    au->wfx.nBlockAlign=wav->fmt.wBlockAlign;
    au->wfx.nChannels=wav->fmt.wChannels;
    au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec=wav->fmt.dwSamplesPerSec;
    au->wfx.wBitsPerSample=wav->fmt.wBitsPerSample;
    }
    else
    { if (au->wfx.wFormatTag!=wav->fmt.wFormatTag) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec!=wav->fmt.dwAvgBytesPerSec) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nBlockAlign!=wav->fmt.wBlockAlign) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nChannels!=wav->fmt.wChannels) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec!=wav->fmt.dwSamplesPerSec) badformat=true;
    if (au->wfx.wBitsPerSample!=wav->fmt.wBitsPerSample) badformat=true;
    }
    if (badformat) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; return AVIERR_BADFORMAT;}
    //
    if (au->as==0) // create the stream if necessary
    { AVISTREAMINFO ahdr; ZeroMemory(&ahdr,sizeof(ahdr));
    ahdr.fccType=streamtypeAUDIO;
    ahdr.dwScale=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwRate=au->wfx.nSamplesPerSec*au->wfx.nBlockAlign; 
    ahdr.dwSampleSize=au->wfx.nBlockAlign;
    ahdr.dwQuality=(DWORD)-1;
    HRESULT hr = AVIFileCreateStream(au->pfile, &au->as, &ahdr);
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(au->as,0,&au->wfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {if (buf!=0) delete[] buf; au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    }
    //
    // now we can write the data
    unsigned long numbytes = wav->dat.size;
    unsigned long numsamps = numbytes*8 / au->wfx.wBitsPerSample;
    HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(au->as,au->nsamp,numsamps,wav->dat.data,numbytes,0,NULL,NULL);
    if (buf!=0) delete[] buf;
    if (hr!=AVIERR_OK) {au->iserr=true; return hr;}
    au->nsamp+=numsamps; return S_OK;
}



unsigned int FormatAviMessage(HRESULT code, char *buf,unsigned int len)
{ const char *msg="unknown avi result code";
    switch (code)
    { case S_OK: msg="Success"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADFORMAT: msg="AVIERR_BADFORMAT: corrupt file or unrecognized format"; break;
    case AVIERR_MEMORY: msg="AVIERR_MEMORY: insufficient memory"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEREAD: msg="AVIERR_FILEREAD: disk error while reading file"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEOPEN: msg="AVIERR_FILEOPEN: disk error while opening file"; break;
    case REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG: msg="REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG: file type not recognised"; break;
    case AVIERR_READONLY: msg="AVIERR_READONLY: file is read-only"; break;
    case AVIERR_NOCOMPRESSOR: msg="AVIERR_NOCOMPRESSOR: a suitable compressor could not be found"; break;
    case AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED: msg="AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED: compression is not supported for this type of data"; break;
    case AVIERR_INTERNAL: msg="AVIERR_INTERNAL: internal error"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADFLAGS: msg="AVIERR_BADFLAGS"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADPARAM: msg="AVIERR_BADPARAM"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADSIZE: msg="AVIERR_BADSIZE"; break;
    case AVIERR_BADHANDLE: msg="AVIERR_BADHANDLE"; break;
    case AVIERR_FILEWRITE: msg="AVIERR_FILEWRITE: disk error while writing file"; break;
    case AVIERR_COMPRESSOR: msg="AVIERR_COMPRESSOR"; break;
    case AVIERR_NODATA: msg="AVIERR_READONLY"; break;
    case AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL: msg="AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL"; break;
    case AVIERR_CANTCOMPRESS: msg="AVIERR_CANTCOMPRESS"; break;
    case AVIERR_USERABORT: msg="AVIERR_USERABORT"; break;
    case AVIERR_ERROR: msg="AVIERR_ERROR"; break;
    }
    unsigned int mlen=(unsigned int)strlen(msg);
    if (buf==0 || len==0) return mlen;
    unsigned int n=mlen; if (n+1>len) n=len-1;
    strncpy(buf,msg,n); buf[n]=0;
    return mlen;
}
```

Here is my main:

```
int main ()
{
    const char *fns[] = {"1.bmp","2.bmp","3.bmp","4.bmp","5.bmp"};

    HAVI avi = CreateAvi("test.avi",1000/5,NULL);
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(fns)/sizeof(fns[0]); i++)
    { 
        HBITMAP hbm=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,fns[i],IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        AddAviFrame(avi,hbm);
        DeleteObject(hbm);
    }
    AddAviWav(avi,"wav.wav",SND_FILENAME);
    CloseAvi(avi);

}
```

what should I do in main ?

Answer (score 0):

Since "using DirectShow" is in the tag line, this is what you do using DirectShow. First of all, you don't write to file directly and you don't need to know the structure of the container file/format. Standard [AVI Mux Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) component does the multiplexing, and [File Writer Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does writing for you. [Building the Recompression Graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you an introduction into how things are done (you need the rightmost half of the picture below).

[Pipleine http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC420247.png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC420247.png)

The "difficult" part is that on the source part of the pipeline you have a non-DirectShow stream, a simple sequence of images. You will need in "inject" them into the pipeline/graph so that they go through components and eventually reach the file.

A typical way would be to refer to [Push Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample in Windows SDK and implement a filter which generates video stream. This is where your images will be fed into processing.